# Async function auto return

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux, server-side-rendering

I'm using **react redux** to create an action creator in my app. The point is that when I use **async await** syntax, it auto returns a promise (without the **"return"** keyword). However, when I use old-style promise like **then()**, i have to explicitly type the **"return"** keyword - otherwise it will return `undefined`. Why does this happen?

***app.js*** (createStore):

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
  const store = createStore(reducers, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk));
  const promise = matchRoutes(RouteApp, req.path).map(({ route }) => {
    return route.loadData ? route.loadData(store) : null;
  });
  console.log(promise);
  Promise.all(promise).then(() => {
    res.send(renderApp(req, store));
  });
});
```

***route.js:***

```
export default [
  {
    loadData,
    path: '/',
    component: Landing,
    exact: true,
  },
];
```

***landing.js***

```
function loadData(store) {
  return store.dispatch(fetchUser());
}
export { loadData };
```

When I use ***async await***:

*action.js*

```
export const fetchUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const res = await axios.get('https://react-ssr-api.herokuapp.com/users');
  dispatch({
    type: INFO_USER,
    payload: res.data,
  });
};
```

[image]

When I use ***promise then***:

```
// It doesn't work
export const fetchUser = () => (dispatch) => {
  axios.get('https://react-ssr-api.herokuapp.com/users').then((res) => {
    dispatch({
      type: INFO_USER,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  });
};
```

[image]

***"return"*** keyword

```
// now it works
export const fetchUser = () => (dispatch) => {
  return axios.get('https://react-ssr-api.herokuapp.com/users').then((res) => {
    dispatch({
      type: INFO_USER,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` function always returns a promise, that's its purpose. In case there's no return value, it returns a promise of `undefined`.

As [the reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function#Return_value) states,

> Return value
>
> A Promise which will be resolved with the value returned by the async
>   function, or rejected with an uncaught exception thrown from within
>   the async function.

This `async` function

```
export const fetchUser = () => async (dispatch) => {
  const res = await axios.get('https://react-ssr-api.herokuapp.com/users');
  dispatch({
    type: INFO_USER,
    payload: res.data,
  });
};
```

is syntactic sugar for this function:

```
export const fetchUser = () => (dispatch) => {
  return axios.get('https://react-ssr-api.herokuapp.com/users').then((res) => {
    dispatch({
      type: INFO_USER,
      payload: res.data,
    });
  });
};
```